# Cant Apply css with jquery for particular H1 tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="b" > <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div class="a"> 
    <p class="ABC">A........Z</p> //this could be present in some pages    
  </div> 
</div>
```

I am trying to use `if($("p.ABC")) { $(".b h1").css({'color': 'red'}); }`

so that if p contains class="ABC" css property gets applied on h1 tag. But "if" statement doesn't have any effect on code. Some help please.

Comment: Please provide all the related code (HTML, CSS).

Comment: I think your validation works, however the selector to apply the new color is not well define. let's try this way:
`if($("p.ABC")) { $("h1.b").css({'color': 'red'}); }`

Comment: @JamesGarcia `$("p.ABC")` will always return a JQuery wrapped set object, even if no elements were found to place in it. As such the `if` condition will always proceed to the `true` branch`. See the answer below.

Comment: would this be useful if($("p.ABC").length)

Comment: Thanks @ScottMarcus you're totally right, after you said it I realised it would be `if($("p.ABC").length)` thanks.

Comment: @Shubham Mishra You don't expect to change color to `red`

Answer (score 0):

Use `hasClass` function of jquery. It returns a Boolean if the element in question has a specific class or not.

```js
if($("p").hasClass('ABC')) { $(".b,h1").css({'color': 'red'}); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b" > <h1>Hello</h1> <div class="a"> 
 <p class="ABC">A........Z</p> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't edit questions and include code that the OP didn't write.